# AzureML not able to Schedule Pipeline endpoint

Tags: python, azure-machine-learning-service

I made a minimal `Pipeline` with a unique step in AML. I've publish this pipeline and I have and `id` and REST `endpoint` for it.

When I try to create a schedule on this pipeline, I get no error, but it will never launch.

```
from azureml.core.runconfig import RunConfiguration
from azureml.pipeline.steps import PythonScriptStep

from azureml.pipeline.core import Pipeline

datastore = ws.get_default_datastore()

minimal_run_config = RunConfiguration()
minimal_run_config.environment = myenv # Custom Env with Dockerfile from mcr.microsoft.com/azureml/openmpi4.1.0-ubuntu20.04:latest + openSDK 11 + pip/conda packages
step_name = experiment_name

script_step_1 = PythonScriptStep(
    name=step_name,
    script_name="main.py",
    arguments=args,
    compute_target=cpu_cluster,
    source_directory=str(source_path),
    runconfig=minimal_run_config,
)
pipeline = Pipeline(
    workspace=ws,
    steps=[
        script_step_1,
    ],
)
pipeline.validate()
pipeline.publish(name=experiment_name + "_pipeline")
```

I can trigger this pipeline with REST python

```
from azureml.core.authentication import InteractiveLoginAuthentication
from azureml.pipeline.core import PublishedPipeline
import requests

auth = InteractiveLoginAuthentication()
aad_token = auth.get_authentication_header()

pipelines = PublishedPipeline.list(ws)
rest_endpoint1 = [p for p in pipelines if p.name == experiment_name + "_pipeline"][0]

response = requests.post(rest_endpoint1.endpoint, 
                         headers=aad_token, 
                         json={"ExperimentName": experiment_name,
                               "RunSource": "SDK",
                               "ParameterAssignments": {"KEY": "value"}})
```

But when I use the Schedule, I have no warning, no error and nothing is triggered if I use `start_time` from `ScheduleRecurrence`. If I don't user `start_time`, my pipeline is triggered and launch immediately. And I don't want this. For example I'm running the Schedule setter `today`, but I want it's first trigger to run only the second of each month at 4pm.

```
from azureml.pipeline.core.schedule import ScheduleRecurrence, Schedule
import datetime

first_run = datetime.datetime(2022, 10, 2, 16, 00)

schedule_name = f"Recocpc monthly run PP {first_run.day:02} {first_run.hour:02}:{first_run.minute:02}"

recurrence = ScheduleRecurrence(
    frequency="Month",
    interval=1,
    start_time=first_run,
)

recurrence.validate()

recurring_schedule = Schedule.create_for_pipeline_endpoint(
    ws,
    name=schedule_name,
    description="Recocpc monthly run PP",
    pipeline_endpoint_id=pipeline_endpoint.id,
    experiment_name=experiment_name,
    recurrence=recurrence,
    pipeline_parameters={"KEY": "value"}
)
```

If I comment `start_time`, It will work, but the first run is now, and not when I want.

Answer (score 0):

So I was not aware on how `start_time` was working. It is using DAGs logic like in airflow.

Here is an example:

Today is `10-01-2022` (dd-mm-yyy)

You want your pipeline to run every month, once the on the 10th of each month at 14:00.

Then your start_time is not  `2022-01-10T14:00:00`, but should be `2021-12-10T14:00:00`.

Your scheduler will only trigger if it has made a full revolution of what you are asking him (here one month).

Maybe official documentation should be more explicit on this mecanism for neewbies like me that never used DAGs in their lives.